# Error : undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_155'

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libx264

I had done

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after that i am getting this error while compiling project:

> ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:948: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_155'

Even i tried to build ffmpeg, i still got same error.
Is there any solution or suggestions for this error?

Comment: Check if you have multiple versions of x264 installed. Search for `x264.h`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I had reinstalled x264 in ffmpeg build and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different versions of x264 installed simultaneously. Uninstall one of them or point your project your are compiling to the proper x264 version.